# Cannot add new app through android studio plugin

Tags: crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I followed all instructions on this link https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install but I still cannot see my app in the dashboard. This was never an issue for me before.

Clicking on the +New App only brings me to selecting which kits to use.
Then when trying to distribute it says project is inactive..

The project is definitely not inactive..

How do I fix this?